# NLTK on a production web application

Tags: python, pyramid, nltk

I'd like to incorporate a custom tagger into a web application (running on Pyramid) I'm developing.  I have the tagger working fine on my local machine using NLTK, but I've read that NLTK is relatively slow for production.

It seems that the standard way of storing the tagger is to Pickle it.  On my machine, it takes  a few seconds to load the 11.7MB pickle file.

1. Is NLTK even practical for production?  Should I be looking at [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) or even something like Mahout?
2. If NLTK is good enough, what is the best way to ensure that it properly uses memory, etc.?

Comment: First, are you using Python 2? If so, are you using `pickle` or `cPickle`? Switching to `cPickle` (or to Python 3, where the two implementations are merged into a single module) might turn your few seconds into a few dozen millis. Alternatively, if you need to use the same tagger for all requests, why load it for each request? Load it once (or once per process, or whatever—I don't know Pyramid), and then it doesn't matter how long it takes.

Comment: For evidence on the above, try this: `p=cPickle.dumps(range(1250000)); print timeit.timeit(lambda: pickle.loads(s), number=1); print timeit.timeit(lambda: cPickle.loads(s), number=1)`. I get 4.96s vs. 0.35s on my system.

Comment: I'm using Python 2 and normal pickle.  I'll take a look at cPickle.  Yeah, I wasn't entirely entirely sure the best way to load the file.  I need to look into loading options for Pyramid

Comment: OK, once you've done that, the next step is to perf-test it. "Relatively slow" may still be more than fast enough for your intended purposes, in which case you're perfectly justified in sticking with the toolkit you already know, and already have code for. It should be pretty easy to set up a trivial test app and use a benchmarking tool to determine whether you can handle the expected load (and, if you can't, to profile and figure out how much of the problem is NLTK).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run [text-processing](http://text-processing.com) and its associated [NLP APIs](https://www.mashape.com/japerk/text-processing), and it uses about 2 dozen different pickled models, which are loaded by a Django app (gunicorn behind nginx). The models are loaded as soon as they are needed, and once loaded, they stay in memory. That means whenever I restart the gunicorn server, the first requests that need a model have to wait a few seconds for it load, but every subsequent request gets to use the model that's already cached in RAM. Restarts only happen when I deploy new features, which usually involves updating the models, so I'd need to reload them anyway. So if you don't expect to make code changes very often, and don't have strong requirements on consistent request times, then you probably don't need a separate daemon.

Other than the initial load time, the main limiting factor is memory. I currently only have 1 worker process, because when all the models are loaded into memory, a single process can take up to 1GB (YMMV, and for a single 11MB pickle file, your memory requirements will be much lower). Processing an individual request with an already loaded model is fast enough (usually <50ms) that I currently don't need more than 1 worker, and if I did, the simplest solution is to add enough RAM to run more worker processes.

If you are worried about memory, then do look into scikit-learn, since equivalent models can use significantly less memory than NLTK. But, they are not necessarily faster or more accurate.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, it's very helpful.  Could you point me in the direction of how to load the models into memory on initialization?  I've been Googling "Django cache", etc. but I'd like to make sure that I'm looking at the correct material.

Comment: In some of my modules, I declare an empty dict, and then in the functions that require models, I check if the model is in the dict, and if not, I use nltk.data.load with the pickle filename to load it, and store a reference in the dict. Then all future calls to that function will use the already loaded model. If you want to load the model immediately, then you can do that at the module level, and just declare it, like "mymodel = nltk.data.load('path/to/model.pickle')".

Answer (score 2):

The best way to reduce start-up latency is to run the tagger as a daemon (persistent service) that your web app sends snippets of text to tag. That way your tagger loads only when the system boots up and if/when the daemon needs to be restarted.

Only you can decide if the NLTK is fast enough for your needs. Once the tagger is loaded, you've probably noticed that the NLTK can tag several pages of text without perceivable delay. But resource consumption and the number of concurrent users could complicate things.

Comment: Yes, the tagging speed of NLTK seems sufficient once it is loaded, so it will a question of what happens with multiple users.

Daemons are a completely new area for me.  Would this involve using something like Twisted or Pyro and a queuing system?

Comment: There are countless options, depending on your OS, expected level of cuncurrency, number of CPUs (you could have a pool of "workers"), etc. Jacob's answer describes one possible setup.